Why is velocity used for kinetic energy instead of speed?
This may seem like a self-explanatory question, but if kinetic energy is a scalar quantity, and squaring the velocity essentially removes its vector quality, why not use speed instead?
I have a hunch that this might have something to do with how you derive it, but is it possible to derive the equation with just speed instead of velocity?
Is it about keeping consistency with other equations? What is the reasoning behind it?

Because physicist think about velocity in general, and don’t use speed.

Kinetic energy is the energy of motion. It doesn't matter what the direction of that motion is.  Perhaps instead of talking about speed, if we said the magnitude of the velocity determines the kinetic energy, you would be more comfortable?

I do think that changing it to the magnitude of velocity helps! Perhaps changing the terminology and trying to think of speed and velocity as completely separate is my problem, thank you!

Because $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v} = s^2$, where $s$ is the speed, this is a semantic question and has no practical impact. You can think of it as the speed squared, if you prefer.


This may seem like a self-explanatory question, but if kinetic energy is a scalar quantity, and squaring the velocity essentially removes its vector quality, why not use speed instead?

It is the same thing. For a velocity $\vec v$ the speed is $v=|\vec v|$. And $$v^2 = |\vec v| \ |\vec v|\ \cos(0)=\vec v\cdot \vec v= \vec v^2$$
